# jQuery .html made submit button doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I am working on a simple color picker where you can click on a color, then a small example of the color appears with a submit button in it so you can select/submit this color.

[image]

I add the submit button to the clicked color with jQuery but for some reason my submit button doesn't submit.

So this piece adds the popup with submit when you click on a color:

```
$(this).addClass('selected_color').html(
        num + '<div class="this_color"><div class="color_example">Color value</div><input type="submit" name="submit_color" value="Selecteer kleur"/></div>');
```

And the submit is in a FORM and has a name "submit_color"

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_color'])) :

    $_SESSION['wz_color'] = $_POST['wz_color'];

endif;
```

I put the value of the color in a hidden field with name wz_color.

But why does my button not submit? Is this because it is added by jquery later?

Comment: Needs a form and method POST

Comment: We need to know (a) what your `<form>` tag looks like, and (b) whether your submit button is contained inside of it. If so, everything should work fine. A reproduction of the problem at http://jsfiddle.net would be helpful to us.

Comment: Yes, and I had already said "And the submit is in a FORM and has a name "submit_color" ;) And has also method post.

Comment: I can give the link to my example if you want?

Comment: Ah oops, give us a fiddle

Comment: Here a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xHH86/

Comment: You appear to be including jQuery twice, the second time as `http://www.glasbestellen.nl/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on a button, the `click` event is propagating up to the `<span>` that contains it, and that event handler is being triggered again. This appears to be interfering with the form submission.

Try blocking it immediately:

```
 $(this).addClass('selected_color').html(num + '<div class="this_color"><div class="color_example">Color value</div><input type="submit" name="submit_color" value="Selecteer kleur"/></div>');
 $('[name=submit_color]').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ve5Kh/

---

Note that delegating the cancellation using `$(document).on('click','[name=submit_color], function(e) {...})` doesn't work, apparently because the event bubbles up to the `span` before it bubbles all the way up to the `document`.

Comment: I just wish I could figure out WHY it was screwing up the submit. My best guess is, when the event bubbles up to the `span`, the button you just clicked is destroyed (and immediately recreated), so no other events (including submitting the form) can take place.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the form tag.

```
$(this).addClass('selected_color').html(
        num + '<div class="this_color">
        <div class="color_example">Color value</div>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <input type="submit" name="submit_color" value="Selecteer kleur"/>
            </form>
        </div>');
```

Comment: I can give the link to my example if you want?

Comment: Sure, that is a lot better.

Comment: Show us all your code that you are currentl using, it'll be much easier. From what I can conclude is that it doesn't seem like it has any action on the form. Just show us the code.

Comment: @AttisBarros You should add that to your answer as that is the actual problem (the missing `action` attribute).

Comment: No missing action, I handle with php in the same document.

Comment: @Robbert Then you need an empty `action=''`, adding that in firebug to your page (not the fiddle) allows me to post. Creating valid html greatly reduces the chance of problems.

Comment: I have included the action as empty here, if what @jeroen says is correct then try the following method. exactly as it is above. And I had already included the action jeroen, it should work just fine with the code above.

Comment: @AttisBarros No, you should remove your `form` tag as there already is a form tag surrounding the whole section and you cannot have nested forms. See the example page and the fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are appending an element to the "form" (with position absolute - not sure if this matters) and the form doesn`t recognize the submit button as her own.
You should load the submit button as the page renders and then move it around.

Comment: No it does not matter

Comment: "The form doesn`t recognize the submit button as her own. You should load the submit button as the page renders and then move it around."

Check and see that this is the problem before you down vote. :)

Comment: Yeah so that's what I thought.. But @AttisBarros are you sure the loading later is not the problem?

Comment: Try to include it between the <form></form> tag as the page renders and then move it around and you will see that it works.